# Select list filter json data

Tags: javascript, json

I want to do filtering from json by select list. now when I choose value from the select list, it gives selected products at the end of the list, and I want to show only those selected

```
function showContent(data) {
    const contentBox = document.querySelector('#content__products');
    const select = document.querySelector('.products__select');

    data.map(function (product) {
        return selectCat(product)
    })
}

function selectCat(product) {
    const select = document.querySelector('.products__select');

    createProduct(product)

    select.addEventListener('change',() => {
        if(select.value == product.cat) {
            createProduct(product);
        } 
    })
}

function createProduct(product) {
    const contentBox = document.querySelector('#product__list');
    const element = prepareElement('div',['product__elem']);
    const imageElement = prepareElement('img', ['product__img'], element);
    const nameProd = prepareElement('p',['product__name'], element);
    const catProd = prepareElement('p',['product__cat'], element);

    contentBox.appendChild(element)

    imageElement.setAttribute('src', product.img);
    nameProd.innerText = product.name;
    catProd.innerText = 'Category:' + ' ' + product.cat;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide elements that don't match to your filter. In your code, I assume that you need to clean the container with products first.

```
function selectCat(product) {
    const select = document.querySelector('.products__select');

    createProduct(product)

    select.addEventListener('change',() => {
        var contentBox = document.getElementById('product__list');
        while (contentBox.firstChild) {
            contentBox.removeChild(contentBox.firstChild);
        }
        if(select.value == product.cat) {
            createProduct(product);
        } 
    })
}
```